# What's the right way to actually get this search functionality to work?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, searchview

I have this app which displays a list of "coins" to the users . This list was parsed from an JSON API and I used Jetpack Compose for the UI. I implemented

Here is the code of the Jetpack composable list of "coins"

```
@Composable
fun CoinListScreen(
navController: NavController, 
viewModel: CoinListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
val state = viewModel.state.value

Surface {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Column {
androidx.compose.foundation.Image(painter = painterResource(id =   R.drawable.ic_baseline_currency_bitcoin_24),
                contentDescription = "BTC",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(CenterHorizontally)
                    .size(50.dp, 50.dp)
            )

            SearchBar(
                hint = "Search..",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ){

           viewModel.searchCoinsList(it) **//here I'm calling my search function from the view model, inside my search bar**

            }


            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {



                items(state.coins) { coin ->

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))

                    CoinListItem(
                        coin = coin,
                        onItemClick = {
                            navController.navigate(Screen.CoinDetailScreen.route + "/${coin.id}")
                        }
                    )
                    Divider()
                }
             }
        }
            if (state.error.isNotBlank()) {
                Text(
                    text = state.error,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
            if (state.isLoading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
            }
        }
    }

}

**//and this Is my composable search bar**
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
hint: String = "",
onSearch: (String) -> Unit = {}
) {


var text by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
var isHint by remember {
    mutableStateOf(hint != "")
}
Box(modifier = modifier){
    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
            onSearch(it)
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        singleLine = true,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .shadow(5.dp, CircleShape)
            .background(Color.White, CircleShape)
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
            .onFocusChanged {
                isHint = it.isFocused != true
            }

    )
    if(isHint){
        Text(
            text = hint,
            color = Color.LightGray,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
        )
      }

  }
}
```

and this is my view model, this is where I'm implementing the search function, this is where I'm lost, variables that I'm searching for are name, rank, and symbol from the Coin domain list

```
@HiltViewModel //injecting the use case
class CoinListViewModel @Inject constructor (
private val getCoinsUseCase: GetCoinsUseCase,
    ) : ViewModel() {

//vmstate Live Template, only the view model touches it
        private val _state =
            mutableStateOf(CoinListState())
      val state: State<CoinListState> = _state

**//for search purposes , this is where I'm lost**
private var coinsList = mutableStateOf<List<Coin>>(listOf())
private var cachedCoinsList = listOf<Coin>()
private var isSearchStarting = true
private var isSearching = mutableStateOf(false)

init {
    getCoins()
}

     **//for search purposes , this is where I'm lost**
  fun searchCoinsList(query: String){
    val listToSearch = if(isSearchStarting){
       coinsList.value
    } else {
        cachedCoinsList
    }
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        if(query.isEmpty()){
            coinsList.value = cachedCoinsList
            isSearching.value = false
            isSearchStarting = true
            return@launch
        }
        val results = listToSearch.filter {
            //val iterate: Int = coins.size
            it.name.contains(query.trim(), ignoreCase = true) ||
                    (it.rank.toString() == query.trim()) ||
                    it.symbol.contains(query.trim(), ignoreCase = true)
        }

        if(isSearchStarting){
            cachedCoinsList = coinsList.value
            isSearchStarting = false
        }
        coinsList.value = results
        isSearching.value = true
      }
   }

//function that calls our GetCoinsUseCase and puts the data inside the state object
//to display that in the UI
  private fun getCoins() {


        //overwrote the invoke function earlier for the use case which allows us to call the use case as a function
        getCoinsUseCase().onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.SUCCESS -> {
                    _state.value =
                        CoinListState(coins = result.data ?: arrayListOf())
                }
                is Resource.ERROR -> {
                    _state.value =

                            CoinListState(
                                error = result.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                            )

                }
                is Resource.LOADING -> {
                    _state.value = CoinListState(isLoading = true)
                }

            }

        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)

}
```

}

CoinsListState data class used in view model

```
data class CoinListState(
val isLoading: Boolean = false,
val coins: ArrayList<Coin> = arrayListOf(),
val error: String = ""
)
```

this is my "GetCoinsUseCase" to get the coins

```
class GetCoinsUseCase @Inject constructor(
private val repository: CoinRepository
) {
// overwriting the operator fun invoke allows us to call the use case
//GetCoinsUseCase as if it was a function, and we return a flow because
// we want to emit states LOADING -> for progress bar, SUCCESS -> attach list of coins,
// and ERROR
operator fun invoke(): kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<Resource<ArrayList<Coin>>> =   flow {
       try {
                 emit(Resource.LOADING<ArrayList<Coin>>())
           //we mapped it to toCoin because we returning a list of coin, not coinDTO
           val coins = repository.getCoins().map { it.toCoin() }
           emit(Resource.SUCCESS<ArrayList<Coin>>(coins as ArrayList<Coin>))

       }catch (e: HttpException){
           emit(Resource.ERROR<ArrayList<Coin>>(e.localizedMessage ?: "An unexpected error occurred"))
       }catch (e: IOException){
            emit(Resource.ERROR<ArrayList<Coin>>("Couldn't reach server. Check connection"))

       }
   }
}
```

just the coin repository that is implemented in another place

```
interface CoinRepository {

//repository definitions
suspend fun getCoins() : ArrayList<CoinDTO>

suspend fun getCoinById(coinId: String) : CoinDetailDTO
```

}

This is my domain - Domain - only contains the data needed
data class Coin(
var id: String,
var isActive: Boolean,
var name: String,
var rank: Int,
var symbol: String
)
and this is how I'm mapping it

```
data class CoinDTO(
val id: String,
@SerializedName("is_active")
val isActive: Boolean,
@SerializedName("is_new")
val isNew: Boolean,
val name: String,
val rank: Int,
val symbol: String,
val type: String
)


fun CoinDTO.toCoin(): Coin {
return Coin(
    id = id,
    isActive = isActive,
    name = name,
    rank = rank,
    symbol =  symbol,
   // logo = CoinDetailLogo(logo = String()).logo
)
}
```

Coin list item if needed for reference, this is what is displayed to the user in the list

```
@Composable
fun CoinListItem (

coin: Coin,
onItemClick: (Coin) -> Unit
) {
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable { onItemClick(coin) }
        .padding(20.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
  ) {
    Text(
        text = "${coin.rank}. ${coin.name} (${coin.symbol})",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
    )
    Text(
        text = if(coin.isActive) "active" else "inactive",
        color = if(coin.isActive) Color.Green else Color.Red,
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
        modifier = Modifier.align(CenterVertically)
    )
   }

 }
```

as well as the "Resource" generic for states

```
//UIStates
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null) {
class SUCCESS<T>(data: T) : Resource<T>(data)
class ERROR<T>(message: String, data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data, message)
class LOADING<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
}
```

again, given this info, how can I get the function searchCoinList in the view model to correctly view the searched data (name, rank, or symbol) when it is called in the CoinListScreen inside the Search Bar. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to implement a basic instant search functionality. It's pretty easy to achieve using Kotlin's `StateFlow` and its operators. Consider the following implementation with description:

```
// CoinListViewModel

private val queryFlow = MutableStateFlow("")
private val coinsList = mutableStateOf<List<Coin>>(listOf())

init {
    queryFlow
        .debounce(300) // filters out values that are followed by the newer values within the given timeout. The latest value is always emitted.
        .filterNot { query -> userInput.isEmpty() } //  filter the unwanted string like an empty string in this case to avoid the unnecessary network call.
        .distinctUntilChanged() // to avoid duplicate network calls
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // Changes the context where this flow is executed to Dispatchers.IO
        .flatMapLatest { query -> // to avoid the network call results which are not needed more for displaying to the user
            getCoinsUseCase(query).catch { emitAll(flowOf(emptyList())}
        }
        .onEach { coins: List<Coin> -> // go through each list of Coins
            coinsList.value = coins
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}

fun searchCoinsList(query: String) {
    queryFlow.value = query
}
```

Comment: getCoinsUseCase doesn't take a parameter "query"

Comment: How do you link the queryFlow to the Composable?